# Redirect data from several files into one master file

Tags: bash

I have multiple data files and I want to redirect some information from these files to another master file.

First I create the column headers in the master file. Then I attempt to transfer data from other files to the master file under the correct columns.

#### Create column headers in master file:

```
awk '
BEGIN {OFS="      "; print "%eval_id", "SF1", "power"}
' > output.dat
```

#### First column in master file is for loop index (1, 2, 3 ...):

```
for i in {1..2}; do
    echo "$i" >> output.dat 
done
```

#### Second column in master file, SF1, (extract data from sf1.dat which is a single column file)

#### Third column in master file, power, (extract data from power.dat which is also a single column file)

Outcome in 3 column format:

```
%eval_id      SF1      power
1             23       300
2             45       650
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simplest Way**

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {OFS="      "; print "%eval_id", "SF1", "power"}' > output.dat
index=0
while IFS= read -r sf1 && IFS= read -r power <&3; do
      index=$(( $index + 1))
      echo -e $index"\t"$sf1"\t"$power >> output.dat

done <sf1.dat 3<power.dat
```

**Explanation:** Read your files inside your loop and perform your operations line by line.